# Is there somewhere I can see my favor with all the giants?

Tags: glitch-2011

The only way I know to find out my current favor is to ask a shrine, and this only tells me the favor I've accrued for one giant. Is there any way to view all my favor ratings simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has now been implemented in the game. You can head over to http://www.glitch.com/giants/favor/ to see your favour with each giant, the amount of iMG that can be earned from donations for the day and any outstanding uncollected emblems. The link is found near the bottom of the homepage beside the link to the leaderboard. You can also find the page in game when you check your favor at any giant's shirine.

Answer (score 1):

For now, your only method is to do it oldschool. Either:

- Jot down on a piece of paper your favour for each <strike>God</strike> Giant, update each time you make a donation.
- Jot down in notepad (or your favourite text editor) your favour for each Giant, update each time you make a donation.